# Construct (sparse) NumPy array from code that computes the operator/matrix-vector product?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, autodiff

In scientific computation, we often have to construct matrices that compute differential operators. It is often easier to write the code that applies the operator than to explicitly construct the matrix. Is there a library that takes the code (assuming it only uses linear operations) and outputs the matrix, ideally in sparse form?

Example:

```
# computes finite differences
def myop(a):
  return a[1:]-a[:-1]

a = np.array(5)
myop(a)
```

computes the finite differences of the "a" vector. I now want to so something like

```
a = some_library.array(5)
op = myop(a)
print(op.as_matrix())
```

which should give me the matrix representation:

```
[[-1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, -1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, -1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, -1, 1]]
```

Having the matrix is very useful, for example for computing the transposed operator or analyzing the sparsity patterns. Technically it should be possible to use automatic differentiation tools and extract the Jacobian of op(), but I didn't find any AD libraries that efficiently deal with the whole Jacobian, in particular if it is sparse. They all seem to either do one pass per row or one per column of the Jacobian, which is horribly slow even for only a few hundreds of variables.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way:

```
In [568]: arr = np.zeros((4,5),int)
In [569]: arr[np.arange(4),np.arange(4)]=-1
In [570]: arr[np.arange(4),np.arange(1,5)]=1
In [571]: arr
Out[571]: 
array([[-1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  1]])
```

There are various `np.diag...` functions, but since your don't want a square matrix I though this would be easier.

The `scipy.sparse` library is often used for finite-difference problems, and has various `dia` constructors.  But that requires more reading.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way we're usually doing it (using `sparse.diags` and Kronecker products). It becomes really messy very quickly though if you have multiple dimensions, varying boundary conditions etc., so I'm looking for a more efficient way to reuse the intuitive explicit code.